# Realm onChange listeners and RealmResults

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

In my application, I use a RealmChangeListener in every activity/fragment to refresh my UI whenever a change happens.

I do notice however that when onChange() is called, the realmResult lists I have are not up to date, which causes exceptions to be thrown.

My question is, should I requery each realmResult list I have in the Realm onChangeListener? (it is a workaround but defeats the purpose of having a RealmResult list which is lively updated!)

Comment: I think you are currently experiencing a bug that will be fixed in 1.0.1: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in Realm 1.0.0, i just noticed the update, thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that this problem no longer occurs with 1.0.1?

Comment: No because they have not released 1.1.0 nor 1.0.1 yet, I just tried a compile and gradle didn't find it... hopefully they'll do soon (but I'm sure that this problem is from Realm, there is a race issue between who gets called first, Realm listeners or List listeners, which only occurred when I upgraded to 1.0.0)

Comment: You can probably access `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` as a snapshot through `repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}`